# Alternate For livequery to attach events for paginated grids

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, livequery

I am using [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) for my project for attaching events in links in table/grid. The grid is paginated ajax calls.
**The confirmable link shows up a dialog when clicked. This click event is attached to the grid using livequery.**
Below is a *mockup* of the grid/table structure. The #ajaxGrid part is returned as HTML in the pagination ajax call.

```
<div id="ajaxgridDiv">
  <div id="ajaxGrid">
     <a href="#" class="confirmableLink">Click here for a Jquery UI dialog</a>
     <div class="paginator">
      //links to prev/next  pages.
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of livequery in such a  situation. My problem arises from the fact that I cannot attach a **'load'** event using delegate as such an event is not bubbled up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could come up with was :
to return a script snippet along with the ajaxGrid HTML like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
     $('ajaxGrid').trigger('ajaxGridLoadEvent');
});
</script>
```

and configure delegation in the main page as:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
     $('ajaxGridDiv').delegate('#ajaxGrid','ajaxGridLoadEvent',function(){
         //attach click events to the confirmableLinks 
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This might not be the best answer available. However I tried using this and it works without in any issues.